# I need to pass into a function and return all the account details in order to tidy up my code java

Tags: java, methods, getter

New to Stack Overflow so go easy on me. This is a pretty basic question but I am just unsure.  I have the following two functions in Java, and I attempting to clean up my code more.  I was wondering how to create another function that would create a new account, pass in all the parameters of `setAccountDetailsTesterOne` in order to get a function that I could call in `addTestAccounts` that would be like `getAccountDetails()` and this would do all of `setAccountDetailsTesterOne.`

```
 private void addTestAccounts(DSLContext sql) {
    Account account = new Account();
    setAccountDetailsTesterOne(sql, account);
}

private void setAccountDetailsTesterOne(DSLContext sql, Account account) {
    account.setEmail("tester1@gmail.com");
    account.setPassword("Tester1#");
    account.hashPassword();
    account.getPasswordSalt();
    account.setFirstName("Tester");
    account.setLastName("One");
    account.setRole(Roles.lecturer);
    account.setInstitutionId(getInstitutionId(sql,"1000000"));
    addAccount(account, sql);
}
```

Any help, advice or tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: please make me clear. you want another function named `getAccountDetails` that will be called  from `addTestAccounts` and will create an account like it done  `addTestAccounts` and then

Comment: Yes, I want a function that will be instead of setAccountDetailsTesterOne(sql,account).  This function should create a new account and pass in the email,password,etc so that whenever I call this function in addTestAccounts everything is created from this one function.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void addTestAccounts(DSLContext sql) {
Account account = createAccountWithDetails(sql);

}


private Account createAccountWithDetails(DSLContext sql) 
{

Account account = new Account();
account.setEmail("tester1@gmail.com");
account.setPassword("Tester1#");
account.hashPassword();
account.getPasswordSalt();
account.setFirstName("Tester");
account.setLastName("One");
account.setRole(Roles.lecturer);
account.setInstitutionId(getInstitutionId(sql,"1000000"));
addAccount(account, sql);
return account ;
}
```

Comment: i am not sure if this is what you want . let me know.

Comment: I was thinking more the way Vihung suggested Saif. Apologies for the question not being very clear, did not know how to put it into words. Many thanks for taking the time out to help me everyone!

Comment: sure thing. happy codding.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to return the Account ref from the setAccountDetailsTesterOne method and then use it in the new method as follows

```
private void addTestAccounts(DSLContext sql) {
    Account account = setAccountDetailsTesterOne(sql);

}

// this method will create new account add details and return it to the previous method
private Account setAccountDetailsTesterOne(DSLContext sql) {
Account account = new Account();
    account.setEmail("tester1@gmail.com");
    account.setPassword("Tester1#");
    account.hashPassword();
    account.getPasswordSalt();
    account.setFirstName("Tester");
    account.setLastName("One");
    account.setRole(Roles.lecturer);
    account.setInstitutionId(getInstitutionId(sql,"1000000"));
    addAccount(account, sql);
return account;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of patterns that you can use.

I am assuming here that Account is a domain object - something that represents a data entity.

The general convention is that getters and setters (e.g. `public X getX()` and `public void setX(X x)`) are accessors and modifiers for properties of an object (a Java Bean).

To create a new instance of your object, you could create a method, say,

```
Account createNewAccount(String email, String password, String firstName, String lastName, Roles role, Institution institution) {
  Account account = new Account();
  account.setEmail(email);
  account.setPassword(password);
  account.hashPassword();
  account.getPasswordSalt();
  account.setFirstName(firstName);
  account.setLastName(lastName);
  account.setRole(role);
  account.setInstitutionId(Institution);

  return account;
}
```

Alternatively, you could specify a constructor for the Account object that does essentially the same thing.

Generally, you would separate the creation of the object and the persistence of the object into a repository, so somewhere else, you may need to do this

```
someMethod(...)
{
  ...
  Institution institution = repo.getInstitution(institutionId)
  Account account = createNewAccount(..., ..., institution);
  repo.addAccount(account);
 ...
}
```

where the assumption is that the variable `repo` represents where the objects are being persisted (in effect whatever is happening inside `getInstitution(sql, institutionId)` - this does not necessarily belong in the data object code).